# Flavor for lib(dart) folder in Flutter like src folder in Android

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I have 5 flavor in my Flutter Application say A,B,C,D and E. For Android app I have added all flavors in app/build.gradle flie as:

```
productFlavors{
        A{
            applicationIdSuffix ".a"
        }
        B{
            applicationIdSuffix ".b"
        }
        ......
        ......
       E{
            applicationIdSuffix ".e"
        }
    }
```

Similarly in src folder I have created Folder A,B,C,D and E for all flavors so that I can use different java classes and resources as flavor wise.

```
src
 |--A
 |--B
 |--C
 |--D
 |--E
 |--main
 |--debug
 |--profile
```

But problem is that, In Flutter, we have only one lib(dart code) folder. I want to separate dart files flavor wise. Because it may possible all flavor has different widgets. E.g If A has a widget xyz than I don't want to include xyz widget in other flavor while building its APK.

I want to separate code in lib folder like src in Android.

Answer (score 0):

For flavors in flutter you need to create AppConfig.dart where in you can add follows:

```
class AppConfig extends InheritedWidget {
  AppConfig(
      {this.appDisplayName,
      this.appInternalId,
      this.stringResource,
      this.colorResource,
      Widget child})
      : super(child: child);

  final String appDisplayName;
  final String appInternalId;
  final StringResource stringResource;
  final ColorResource colorResource;

  static AppConfig of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<AppConfig>();
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(InheritedWidget oldWidget) => false;
}

abstract class StringResource {
  String APP_DESCRIPTION;
}

abstract class ColorResource {
  var basicColor;
}
```

and you may add flavor dart files like :
main_A.dart

```
void main() {
  var configuredApp = AppConfig(
    appDisplayName: "App A",
    appInternalId: "A/",//this is for assets folder
    stringResource: StringResourceApp1(),
    colorResource: ColorA(),
    child: MyApp(),
  );
 mainCommon();
      runApp(configuredApp);
    }
```

main_B.dart

```
void main() {
  var configuredApp = AppConfig(
    appDisplayName: "App B",
    appInternalId: "B/",//this is for assets folder
    stringResource: StringResourceApp2(),
    colorResource: ColorB(),
    child: MyApp(),
  );

  mainCommon();
  runApp(configuredApp);
}
```

A change your main dart file rename it to main_common.dart and add this method if needed.

```
void mainCommon() {
  // Here would be background init code, if any
}
```

Now in edit configurations and edit for a flavor as below

[Add path to your flavor main_flavor.dart file and add build flavor name as same used in gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ers6.png)

and do the same for other flavors too!

Comment: Do we need to create multiple lib folder for dart code?

Comment: But this is my question. I know how to manage flavor in android but how I can manage dart code with flutter?. Please check my question once again and Thanks for reply.

Comment: Just updated my answer , do try using it.

Comment: Hi, I am doing same In may app. But my problem is that If I have 2 widgets say AWidget (10kb in size) and BWidget(10kb in size).  Now for flavor A only AWidget must include in code not BWidget. Similar for flavor B. My build size should remain less than 20kb.